# Hibernate - the custom query did not find the entity by the child parameter for ManyToOne unidirectional relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with retrieving an entity using the child's entity as a search parameter. Entities are related to many to one relationship as unidirectional and each object is fetched as FetchType.LAZY.
When I looking for an entity by a child entity, the result is null. But when I set to fetch as Eager it is correct.

My Entities:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner")
public class PartnerEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    public PartnerEntity(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
}


@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "point")
public class PointEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "partner_Id")
    private PartnerEntity partnerEntity;
    public PointEntity(PartnerEntity partnerEntity) {
        this.partnerEntity = partnerEntity;
    }
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "orer")
public class OrdEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PAYMENT_POINT_ID")
    private PointEntity pointEntity;
    public OrdEntity(PointEntity pointEntity) {
        this.pointEntity = pointEntity;
    }
}



@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "BL")
public class BLEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARTNER_LOGIN", referencedColumnName = "login")
    private PartnerEntity partnerEntity;
    private String number;
    public BLEntity(PartnerEntity partnerEntity, String number) {
        this.partnerEntity = partnerEntity;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

And I looking for BLEntity using OrdEntity child:

```
 final OrdEntity byId = ordRepo.findById(id);
 final PartnerEntity partnerEntity = order.getPointEntity().getPartnerEntity();
 final BLEntity blEntityResult= blRepo.findOneByNumberAndPartner(number, partnerEntity);
```

The object partnerEntity  is not null, it is correct object.
I got blEntityResult as null but if I change in PointEntity fetch to FetchType.EAGER, blEntityResult is not null(correct).

My custom query in repository below:

```
public interface BLRepo extends JpaRepository<BLEntity, Long> {
@Query("select b from BLEntity b where b.number = :number and b.partnerEntity= :partner")
BLEntity findOneByNumberAndPartner(@Param("number") String number, @Param("partner") PartnerEntity partner);
}
```

why does happens, if the partner object being downloaded is not null and is correct?

Comment: Why do you only generate Getter? What about the Setter? They are needed by JPA.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added Setter but result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the mapping in both sides,
because of default fetch type for @AllToMany=Lazy and @ManyToAll = Eager. 
just add below code inside PartnerEntity.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="partnerEntity" , fetch = FetchType.Eager )
 List<BLEntity> blEntity = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I change FetchType into Eager in PointEntity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "partner_Id")
private PartnerEntity partnerEntity;
```

And everything is ok, but I don't understand why it does not work with PaymentType.Lazy. When I am looking for:

```
final PartnerEntity partnerEntity = order.getPointEntity().getPartnerEntity();
```

I get correct entity "PartnerEntity" which has proper login's field (login'field has value "test").

When I turned logged level to 'TRACE' I saw, Hibernate not binding correct login's parameter, it set null instead "test") why? :)